# How to load this same list to few dropdowns on client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, .net-3.5, viewstate

I have page with 3 dropdowns that contains large number of this same data (users list). I can't use load on demand to load only part of list - I need whole list.
 I need to handle this and not have problems with invalid viewstate error after postback - I have this problem sometimes when I'm changing list of options in dropdown on client side.

How to minimalize size of page by sending this list once in html and then load it to each dropdown without problems after postback?

Comment: When you change the `DropDownList` on the client side, does it affect the other lists?

Comment: Might I suggest using an autocomplete instead of a drop down and referencing a webservice?  If the size of your dataset is large enough to warrant concern of page transfer times/HTML size, it probably doesn't belong in it's full glory in a single control, much less multiple controls on the same page.